# ignoring data insert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php file.in that file I am inserting data into 3 tables. When I am trying to insert data into bhavcopypc table at that mysql start to skip inserting data in this table.
bhavcopypc has around 900000 records in this table.  If I have empty table than it insert properly but when that table have more records. At that time mysql start to skip inserting data in this table

```
$smarty = new SmartyWWW();
$filePath = "./bhavcopiesfo";
$handle = '';
$monthOk = '';
$monthInt= '';
$monthIntExp= '';
$expiryDate2 = '';
$expiryDateBc = '';
$generalf_oQuery = "SELECT * FROM generalf_o";
$generalf_oResult = mysql_query($generalf_oQuery);
while($generalf_oRow = mysql_fetch_array($generalf_oResult))
{
  $fileName = $generalf_oRow['fileName'];
  $year  = substr($generalf_oRow['fileName'],7,4);
  $month = substr($generalf_oRow['fileName'],4,3);
  $date  = substr($generalf_oRow['fileName'],2,2);
  switch ($month)
  {
    case "JAN":
      $monthOk = '01';
      break;
    case "FEB":
      $monthOk = '02';
      break;
    case "MAR":
      $monthOk = '03';
      break;
    case "APR":
      $monthOk = '04';
      break;
    case "MAY":
      $monthOk = '05';
      break;
    case "JUN":
      $monthOk = '06';
      break;
    case "JUL":
      $monthOk = '07';
      break;
    case "AUG":
      $monthOk = '08';
      break;
    case "SEP":
      $monthOk = '09';
      break;
    case "OCT":
      $monthOk = '10';
      break;
    case "NOV":
      $monthOk = '11';
      break;
    case "DEC":
      $monthOk = '12';
      break;
  }

  $sDate = $year."-".$monthOk."-".$date;

//  //Check that data already in bhavcopyf_o table :Start
    $storedbhavf_oQuery = "SELECT * FROM storedbhavf_o
                           WHERE storDate = '".$sDate."'";
    $storedbhavf_oResult = mysql_query($storedbhavf_oQuery);
    if($storedbhavf_oRow = mysql_fetch_array($storedbhavf_oResult))
    {
      if($storedbhavf_oRow['status'] == "Ok")
        $varStoreBhav = false;
      else
      {
        $varStoreBhav = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $insertStor = "INSERT INTO storedbhavf_o(storDate,status)
                    VALUES('".$sDate."','started')";
      $insertStorResult = mysql_query($insertStor);
      $varStoreBhav = true;
    }
    //Check that data already in bhavcopyf_o table :End

  if($varStoreBhav = true)
  {
    $row = 0;
    $scLineCount = 1;
    $FOLineCount = 1;
    $NSELineCount = 1;
    $handle = fopen($filePath."/".$fileName, "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
      if($row > 0)
      {
        $num = count($data);

        $exchange     = 'F_O';
        $expiryDate   = $data[2];
        $strikePrice  = $data[3];
        $bhavcopyDate = $data[14];
        $contractCode = $data[1];
        $openPrice    = $data[5];
        $highPrice    = $data[6];
        $lowPrice     = $data[7];
        $closePrice   = $data[8];
        $openInterest = $data[12];
        $disc207 = strpos($data[2],'-',0);
        if($disc207 == 1)
        {
          $monthStree = substr($data[2],2,3);
        }
        else if($disc207 == 2)
        {
          $monthStree = substr($data[2],3,3);
        }
        else
        {
        }
        $monthStr = $monthStree;

        switch ($monthStr)
        {
          case "Jan":
            $monthInt = '01';
            break;
          case "Feb":
            $monthInt = '02';
            break;
          case "Mar":
            $monthInt = '03';
            break;
          case "Apr":
            $monthInt = '04';
            break;
          case "May":
            $monthInt = '05';
            break;
          case "Jun":
            $monthInt = '06';
            break;
          case "Jul":
            $monthInt = '07';
            break;
          case "Aug":
            $monthInt = '08';
            break;
          case "Sep":
            $monthInt = '09';
            break;
          case "Oct":
            $monthInt = '10';
            break;
          case "Nov":
            $monthInt = '11';
            break;
          case "Dec":
            $monthInt = '12';
            break;
        }
        $disc = strpos($data[2],'-',0);
        if($disc == 1)
        {
          $yearDub2 = "20".substr($data[2],8,2);
          $expiryDate2   = $yearDub2."-".$monthInt."-0".substr($data[2],0,1);
          $expiryDateBc = $yearDub2."".$monthStr."0".substr($data[2],0,1);
        }
        else if($disc == 2)
        {
          $yearDub23 = substr($data[2],7,4);
          $expiryDate2   = $yearDub23."-".$monthInt."-".substr($data[2],0,2);
          $expiryDateBc = $yearDub23."".$monthStr."".substr($data[2],0,2);
        }
        else
        {
        }
        ////////For Expiry:Start
        if(strlen(trim($contractCode)) > 0)
        {
          $disc211 = strpos($data[14],'-',0);
          //$pose = strpos($data[14],'-',0) == 1;
          if($disc211 == 1)
          {
            $monthStrExpee = substr($data[14],2,3);
          }
          else if($disc211 == 2)
          {
            $monthStrExpee = substr($data[14],3,3);
          }
          $monthStrExp = $monthStrExpee;
          switch ($monthStrExp)
          {
            case "JAN":
              $monthIntExp = '01';
              break;
            case "FEB":
              $monthIntExp = '02';
              break;
            case "Mar":
              $monthIntExp = '03';
              break;
            case "APR":
              $monthIntExp = '04';
              break;
            case "MAY":
              $monthIntExp = '05';
              break;
            case "JUN":
              $monthIntExp = '06';
              break;
            case "JUL":
              $monthIntExp = '07';
              break;
            case "AUG":
              $monthIntExp = '08';
              break;
            case "SEP":
              $monthIntExp = '09';
              break;
            case "OCT":
              $monthIntExp = '10';
              break;
            case "NOV":
              $monthIntExp = '11';
              break;
            case "DEC":
              $monthIntExp = '12';
              break;
          }

          $disc2 = strpos($data[14],'-',0);
          //$pose = strpos($data[14],'-',0) == 1;
          //echo '<BR>'.substr($data[14],0,1);
          if($disc2 == 1)
          {
            $yearDub = "20".substr($data[14],8,2);
            $bhavcopyDate2 = $yearDub."-".$monthIntExp."-0".substr($data[14],0,1);
          }
          else if($disc2 == 2)
          {
            $yearDub = substr($data[14],7,4);
            $bhavcopyDate2 = $yearDub."-".$monthIntExp."-".substr($data[14],0,2);
          }
          else
          {
          }
        }

        $selectDP = 0;
        $noDuplication ="SELECT fileName 
                           FROM duplicate_fo_check
                          WHERE fileName = '".$fileName."'";
        $resultNoDuplicate = mysql_query($noDuplication);
        if(mysql_num_rows($resultNoDuplicate) != 0)
        {
          $selectDP = '1';
        }
        else
        {
          $selectDP = '0';
        }

        if($selectDP == 0)
        {
          if($data[4] == 'XX')
          {
            //echo "<br />Insert : ".$row;
            $insertData = "INSERT INTO bhavcopyf_o (exchange,bhavcopyDate,contractCode,
                                                    expiryDate,expiryDateBc,openPrice,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,openInterest)
                           VALUES ('".$exchange."','".$sDate."','".$contractCode."',
                                   '".$expiryDate2."','".$expiryDateBc."',
                                   ".$openPrice.",".$highPrice.",".$lowPrice.",".$closePrice.",".$openInterest.")";
            $resultData = mysql_query($insertData);
          }
        }
        $selectDPC = 0;
        $noDuplicationPC ="SELECT fileName 
                             FROM duplicate_pc_check
                            WHERE fileName = '".$fileName."'";
        $resultNoPCDuplicate = mysql_query($noDuplicationPC);
        if(mysql_num_rows($resultNoPCDuplicate) != 0)
        {
          $selectDPC = '1';
        }
        else
        {
          $selectDPC = '0';
        }

        if($selectDPC == 0)
        {
          //echo "<br> ---> ".$data[1];
          //echo "<br />  1 : ".$row." : ".$data[4];
          if(($data[4] == 'CE' || $data[4] == 'PE'))
          {
            //echo "<br /> 2 "; 
            if($data[4] == 'CE')
            {
              $putCall = 'C';
            }
            elseif($data[4] == 'PE')
            {
              $putCall = 'P';
            }
            else
            {
              $putCall = '';
            }

            if($openInterest > 0)
            {
                $insertData = "INSERT INTO bhavcopypc (exchange,bhavcopyDate,contractCode,strikePrice,
                                                       expiryDate,expiryDateBc,openPrice,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,
                                                       openInterest,putCall)
                               VALUES ('".$exchange."','".$sDate."','".$contractCode."',".$strikePrice.",
                                       '".$expiryDate2."','".$expiryDateBc."',
                                       ".$openPrice.",".$highPrice.",".$lowPrice.",
                                       ".$closePrice.",".$openInterest.",'".$putCall."')";
                $resultDataRes = mysql_query($insertData);
                if($resultDataRes)
                {
                  $selectPutCall = "SELECT expiryDate,contractCode,bhavcopyDate,
                                             SUM(openInterest) AS openInterest,
                                             putCall
                                        FROM bhavcopypc
                                       WHERE bhavcopyDate = '".$sDate."'
                                         AND expiryDate = '".$expiryDate2."'
                                         AND contractCode = '".$contractCode."'
                                         AND putCall = '".$putCall."'
                                    GROUP BY contractCode,expiryDate,bhavcopyDate,putCall";
                  $selectPutCallRes = mysql_query($selectPutCall);
                  if($pcRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectPutCallRes))
                  {
                    $expiryDateSelect   = $pcRow['expiryDate'];
                    $contractCodeSelect = $pcRow['contractCode'];
                    $bhavcopyDateSelect = $pcRow['bhavcopyDate'];
                    $openInterestSelect = $pcRow['openInterest'];
                    $putCallSelect      = $pcRow['putCall'];

                    $query1 = "DELETE FROM bhavcopypcoi 
                                              WHERE bhavcopyDate = '".$sDate."'
                                  AND expiryDate = '".$expiryDate2."'
                                    AND contractCode = '".$contractCode."'
                                    AND putCall = '".$putCall."'";
                                  $result1=mysql_query($query1);
                                  if(!$result1)
                                   echo "DELETING FAILED";

                    $insertNewOi = "INSERT INTO bhavcopypcoi (contractCode,expiryDate,bhavcopyDate,openInterest,putCall) 
                    VALUES('".$contractCodeSelect."','".$expiryDateSelect."',
                                        '".$bhavcopyDateSelect."','".$openInterestSelect."','".$putCallSelect."')";
                      $insertNewOiRes = mysql_query($insertNewOi);
                      if(!$insertNewOiRes)
                      {

                      }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
/////////////////// Put Call Data Insert End //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
      $row++;
    }

    $selectChk = 0;
    $noDuplicationChk ="SELECT fileName 
                          FROM duplicate_fo_check
                         WHERE fileName = '".$fileName."'";
    $resultNoChkDuplicate = mysql_query($noDuplicationChk);
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultNoChkDuplicate) != 0)
    {
      $selectChk = '1';
    }
    else
    {
      $selectChk = '0';
    }

    if($selectChk == 0)
    {
        $insertDPC = "INSERT INTO duplicate_fo_check (fileName)
                           VALUES ('".$fileName."')";
        $resultDPC = mysql_query($insertDPC);
      }

      $selectChkPc = 0;
    $noDuplicationChkPc ="SELECT fileName 
                            FROM duplicate_pc_check
                           WHERE fileName = '".$fileName."'";
    $resultNoChkPcDuplicate = mysql_query($noDuplicationChkPc);
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultNoChkPcDuplicate) != 0)
    {
      $selectChkPc = '1';
    }
    else
    {
      $selectChkPc = '0';
    }

    if($selectChkPc == 0)
    {
        $insertDPCPC = "INSERT INTO duplicate_pc_check (fileName)
                           VALUES ('".$fileName."')";
        $resultDPCPC = mysql_query($insertDPCPC);
      }
    fclose($handle);
  }
header("Location: ./txtFileF_OAmit.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say that it starts to skip inserting data, do you mean that some data gets entered and some get skipped or that they are all altogether skipped and no more data can be entered?

Comment: yes it insert some data and after start to skip..

Comment: I didn't understood your question properly but if you are just looking to avoid duplicate inserts you can simply use "insert ignore"

Comment: @Krishna when i am start insert data into table at that time some data inserted into table and some data are ignore automatically by mysql. so i want to know that problem in my code?

Comment: Ok, Got your point. Have you tried to echo the insert queries and tried to manually execute under query window so that you will come to know the error if any character or data issue otherwise just looking at the code it seems difficult to trace this kind of issue.

Comment: invoke your SQL statement in phpmyadmin, if it works fine..check what you are inserting.